# Install User Certificate Via ADB

Tags: android, certificate, adb, x509certificate

Is there a way to install CA certificate (`.crt` file) under the `Security -> Trusted Credential -> User tab` via ADB? or any other "scriptable" way.

Comment: did you solved the problem ?

Comment: The only way to install certificate silently is via Device Policy Manager, and only apps (.apks) can register as DPM, so sadly after long research I reached a dead end.@MohamedELAYADI

Comment: I figured out a way to do this; openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem | head -1>toto

set /p totoVar=<toto

set totoVar=%totoVar%.0 && DEL toto

cat charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem > %totoVar%

echo %totoVar%

openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -in charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem -out nul >> %totoVar%



adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system

adb push %totoVar% /system/etc/security/cacerts/

adb shell mount -o ro,remount,ro /system

adb reboot

Comment: If you're interested in this being easier, star the Google issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168169729?pli=1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, thus i was able to trust charles proxy certificate. it will be added as trusted SSL root certificate.

First you need to get the certificate hash

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem | head -1>hashedCertFile
```

i use windows, store it in a var in a matter to automate the process

```
set /p certHash=<hashedCertFile
    

set certHash=%certHash%.0 && DEL toto
cat charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem > %certHash%

openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -in charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem -out nul >> %certHash%

adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system

adb push %certHash% /system/etc/security/cacerts/

adb shell mount -o ro,remount,ro /system

adb reboot
```

This is the unix version copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48814971/7104283):

```
PEM_FILE_NAME=logger-charles-cert.pem
hash=$(openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in $PEM_FILE_NAME | head -1)
OUT_FILE_NAME="$hash.0"

cp $PEM_FILE_NAME $OUT_FILE_NAME
openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -in $PEM_FILE_NAME -out /dev/null >> $OUT_FILE_NAME

echo "Saved to $OUT_FILE_NAME"
adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
adb push $OUT_FILE_NAME /system/etc/security/cacerts/
adb shell mount -o ro,remount,ro /system
adb reboot
```

Comment: "adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system" not correct, you should use "adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system"

Comment: I have to also set the cert's permission to 644 to make it work. Otherwise the cert is not recognized.

Comment: @Incepter I  do not see, where the certificate is installed? I see that PEM certificate being pushed into the cacerts folder.

Comment: `adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system` -> `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts`

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to this answer [Install User Certificate Via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942851/install-user-certificate-via-adb/46569793#46569793) I was able to adapt a script that works on a bash shell:

```
PEM_FILE_NAME=logger-charles-cert.pem
hash=$(openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in $PEM_FILE_NAME | head -1)
OUT_FILE_NAME="$hash.0"

cp $PEM_FILE_NAME $OUT_FILE_NAME
openssl x509 -inform PEM -text -in $PEM_FILE_NAME -out /dev/null >> $OUT_FILE_NAME

echo "Saved to $OUT_FILE_NAME"
adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
adb push $OUT_FILE_NAME /system/etc/security/cacerts/
adb shell mount -o ro,remount,ro /system
adb reboot
```

(Yes, I know this should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to post it as a comment yet)

Comment: I got this error.

./ssl_pinning.sh: line 3: !!: command not found
head: cert_name=.0: No such file or directory

Comment: @Gorio you might find [this script](https://gist.github.com/cbachert/e580f1ac06ce196a9831beda349fcfa3) helpful. You will surely need to update it a bit (I couldn't copy the resulting file to the /system partition of the AVD but was successful with Genymotion).

Comment: there are too many `ro` and `rw` in your remount commands

Answer (score 11):

I was able to get a **server** cert to show up under the `Trusted Credential -> User` tab (rather than the system tab, which other answers show) with the following steps:

```
#!/bin/bash
subjectHash=`openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in server.crt | head -n 1`
openssl x509 -in server.crt -inform PEM -outform DER -out $subjectHash.0
adb root
adb push ./$subjectHash.0 /data/misc/user/0/cacerts-added/$subjectHash.0
adb shell "su 0 chmod 644 /data/misc/user/0/cacerts-added/$subjectHash.0"
adb reboot
```

Comment: +1 tested on lineages android 10, works like a charm. do not forget to click on "trust"  in `Trusted Credential -> User` after reboot

Answer (score 7):

**2022**: httptoolkit has a good solution to inject a custom cert **without rebooting** into rooted devices/emulators

Details here: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/intercepting-android-https/#injecting-ca-certificates-into-rooted-devices

```
    set -e # Fail on error
    # Create a separate temp directory, to hold the current certificates
    # Without this, when we add the mount we can't read the current certs anymore.

    mkdir -m 700 /data/local/tmp/htk-ca-copy
    # Copy out the existing certificates

    cp /system/etc/security/cacerts/* /data/local/tmp/htk-ca-copy/
    # Create the in-memory mount on top of the system certs folder

    mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /system/etc/security/cacerts
    # Copy the existing certs back into the tmpfs mount, so we keep trusting them

    mv /data/local/tmp/htk-ca-copy/* /system/etc/security/cacerts/
    # Copy our new cert in, so we trust that too

    mv ${certificatePath} /system/etc/security/cacerts/
    # Update the perms & selinux context labels, so everything is as readable as before

    chown root:root /system/etc/security/cacerts/*
    chmod 644 /system/etc/security/cacerts/*
    chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/*
    # Delete the temp cert directory & this script itself

    rm -r /data/local/tmp/htk-ca-copy
    rm ${injectionScriptPath}
    echo "System cert successfully injected"
```

[Source](https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-server/blob/8a4b4d283fbe98694ddd09a44d6e9c9941aa91e2/src/interceptors/android/adb-commands.ts#L200-L253)

Answer (score 7):

Push file to device

```
adb push "C:\path\cacert.cer" "/data/local"
```

Start the CertInstaller

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstallerMain -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t application/x-x509-ca-cert -d file:///data/local/cacert.cer
```

Now finish installing with the prompt that will appear on your device.

Comment: I tried this on my Wear OS watch (Fossil Gen 6). adb does not have permission to upload on "/data/local/", but it is possible to upload to "/data/local/tmp/".

And here are the possible MIME types:

* application/x-x509-ca-cert
* application/x-x509-user-cert
* application/x-x509-server-cert
* application/x-pem-file
* application/pkix-cert
* application/x-pkcs12
* application/x-wifi-config

Comment: Same as @Fulkerson. Mine was forced to set a Screen Lock before being able to install the cert. is there any way to not set Screen Lock?

Comment: @Fulkerson Did you manage to install the certificates on your watch? When running the command I see the UI on the watch but then after tapping OK there's an error toast. When connecting with ADB, the exception is: `W CertInstaller: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.security.CredentialStorage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 1):

This only launches the "do you want to trust this certificate window" on a non-rooted android. It is the answer by @hoghart45 except with a line that ensures you have permission to paste your certificate into the `/data/local/..` directory:

```bash
certificateName=ca.crt
ca_dir_in_phone="/data/local/tmp/try3"
ca_path_in_phone="$ca_dir_in_phone/$certificateName"

adb shell mkdir -m 700 "$ca_dir_in_phone"
adb push "$certificateName" "$ca_path_in_phone"

adb shell am start -n com.android.certinstaller/.CertInstallerMain -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t application/x-x509-ca-cert -d file://"$ca_path_in_phone"
```

[image]

For completeness, [here](https://github.com/HiveMinds/apk-controller/issues) is a WIP Python project WIP that also automates clicking "OK" in a controlled fashion using `uiautomator`. (It verifies it is the ok button before clicking, it does not just send a blind enter, like the `send keyevent 20` command). Disclaimer, I am involved with that project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I first needed to start the emulator as writable:

```
adb start-server
emulator -writable-system -avd Pixel_2_API_24
```

Then you can install certificate:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push c8750f0d.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts
```

https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android